# How do I disable tabbing in child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div element with several children. I need to disable tabbing in all of them. I have been using tabindex but is there any way to disable them all by setting a value in the parent.

I don't want to touch the child divs.

Comment: do you have any running code?

Comment: your question is very generic, could you elaborate your issue further?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your code looks like but you could grab the parent element and add the tabindex attribute to its children that are `input`s using `attr()` as follows:

```js
$(".wrapper").children("input").attr("tabindex", "-1");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" name="1">
  <input type="text" name="2">
  <input type="text" name="3">
  <input type="text" name="4">
</div>
```

NOTE: when you say "I don't want to touch the child divs" I'm assuming you mean you don't want to manually go through every instance and add tabindex as it would be time consuming?

More info: http://api.jquery.com/attr/